# How to get filename from stdin

Tags: python

I am writing a script and i am running it from the console like this

`cat source_text/* | ./mapper.py`

and i would like to get the filename of each file reading at the time. Source texts folder contains a bunch of text files whose filename i need to extract as well in my mapper script.

Is that possible?

```
import sys
import re
import os


# re is for regular expressions
pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
                     re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)


# Read pairs as lines of input from STDIN
for line in sys.stdin:
    ....
```

Comment: I don't think you can get the filename from a pipe. The only thing python sees is the stdin from the stdout of the `cat` command.

Comment: is there a workaround you can suggest?

Comment: That is not possible. You should modify your program to read directly from the files.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python

Comment: if you want the shell to expand the glob then just `./mapper.py source_text/*` and use `sys.argv` to iterate over the files opening them...

Comment: thank you all for your responses, appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks -- and don't forget to accept your preferred solution (whichever you like better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that directly, but fileinput module can help you.

You just have to call you script that way:

```
./mapper.py source_text/*
```

And change it that way:

```
import fileinput
...

# Read pairs as lines of input from STDIN
for line in fileinput.input():
    ...
```

Then the name of the file being processed is available as `fileinput.filename()`, and you can also have access the the number of the line in current file as `fileinput.filelineno()` and still other goodies...

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. You can modify your program to read directly from the files like this:

```
import sys
import re

# re is for regular expressions
pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
                     re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(filename, "rU") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if pattern.search(line) is not None:
                print filename, line,
```

Then you can call it with:

```
$ ./grep_files.py source_text/*
```

Comment: right, and how do i extract the filename to print it lets say in console?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou: The filename is in the `filename` variable.

Comment: ah yes got it how it works now, i am like brand new to python thank you!

Comment: I added some output :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use this instead of cat:

```
grep -r '' source_text/ | ./mapper.py
```

The input for mapper.py will be like:

```
source_text/answers.txt:42
source_text/answers.txt:42
source_text/file1.txt:Hello world
```

You can then retrieve the filename using:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    filename, line = line.split(':', 1)
    ...
```

However Python is more than capable to iterate over files in a directory and reading them line-by-line, for example:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    for line in open(filename):
        ...
```