# sorting replaces filename with <stdin>

Tags: python

I have a mapper.py script and i have a reducer.py script using the sort pipeline.

mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
import fileinput

# Read pairs as lines of input from STDIN
for line in fileinput.input():
   filename = fileinput.filename()
   filename = filename.replace("source_text/", "")

   print filename
```

sorter/reducer

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:

    print line
```

i then run this in my console

```
cat source_text/* | ./mapper.py | sort | ./reducer.py
```

the problem is that while the filename in the mapper correctly shows the filename when it gets passed to the reducer script, it gets replaced with `<stdin>`

my question is how can i pass the real filename to the second script?

Comment: why cant you just write a single python script to do all the operations.

Comment: because i want to use it for Elastic MapReduce (hadoop) in amazon and it needs a mapper and reducer script. I have the whole script working in single file.

Comment: The script isn't reading from whatever source file you think it is; it's reading from standard input. If you want to see file names, you'll have to change how your script takes input.

Comment: @user2357112 what you say is partly true but i do not know of any other way to call both scripts like this? if it was only one script it would go like this,  `source_text/*  ./mapper.py`, but for both scripts it does not seem to work

Comment: (cat source_text/* | ./mapper.py | sort > tempfile.txt | ./reducer tempfile.txt) can you write the output into a temp file after sort then read it in the reducer script?

Comment: @Radan the thing is that i cant run `cat source_text/* | ./mapper.py` because it won't read the filename so i am forced to do it this way, `source_text/*  ./mapper.py`, you can read my other topic here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182156/how-to-get-filename-from-stdin` thats why i have trouble figuring out how to write a second script after the execution of the first one.